# BIRT Reports - Dropping Table elements. Can't find the beforeFactory() script

Tags: java, birt

I need the functionality of being able to show the correct table for a BIRT Report (dropping the ones I don't need to see).  I see plenty of examples of dropping tables and they all say to perform the drop in the beforeFactory() script.  How do I access the beforeFactory() script using the BIRT IDE?  I am used to dropping CrossTab elements from within the beforeOpen() script.  This function works great.  The beforeOpen() script is available when I select a Datasource and selecting the 'script' tab.  I can't find the beforeFactory() script!   BTW - when I try dropping the table inside of the beforeOpen() script, I get a BIRT exception and the report doesn't run.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the outline view select the root of the report-design, and then the script tab as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I am able to select what table I need to display.